# How to move the cursor down a line in 16-bit code?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

Here is the code i wrote I'm trying to write on assembly 8086 like on a regular keyboard but every time i press on enter it goes down a line and writes the second letter in the RAM how do i fix it without resetting the ram lets the user write from the keyboard.

```
data segment
    ; add your data here! 
    msg db ? 
    nxtline db 10,13,'$'
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; add your code here
    xor ax,ax
    mov ah,1        
    xor bx,bx 
    mov bx,offset msg
    ifpressed:
    ;pusha 
    mov ah,1
    int 21h   
    cmp al,0Dh  ;check when enter is pressed
    jz nextline
    mov [bx],al
    add bx,2 
    ;popa 
    jmp ifpressed

    nextline:
     lea dx, nxtline
     mov ah, 9
     int 21h
     jmp ifpressed
    reapet:



    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
  `
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want but int21/01 is input **with echo** so maybe you want int21/08 which is input **without echo**.

Comment: no i want it with echo the only problem is that the second  letter i write is always returning in the begining of a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but every time i press on enter it goes down a line...

That's exactly what the program was created for.
If you don't want this to happen then either remove the next 2 lines from your program:

```
cmp al,0Dh  ;check when enter is pressed
jz nextline
```

or keep these 2 lines but alter the definition of *nxtline* (remove the 13):

```
nxtline db 10,'$'
```

Comment: Due to `msg db ?` and `add bx,2` every next inputted character will destroy the CR in _nxtline_ and later the rest of memory!

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for me with bios interrupts assembler, it`s for dos assembler i think.
Try to change column and row manually by changing dl and dh registers like this:

```
Prompt: mov si, PromptChar
         mov ah, 2
         mov dh, 15  # change row to 15
         mov dl, 0   # change column to 0
         int 10h
         lodsb
         mov ah, 9
         int 10h
         jmp short End
```